# How do I make my OnClick reveal information ONLY for the job post clicked, instead of all of the jobs posts. ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

So i'm creating a job board that will display jobs and, upon clicking the specific job you are interested in, additional information will be shown. The catch is that each time someone click on a specific job post, ALL job posts reveal their additional information. I'm only trying to show the job post that was CLICKED's info. Any help would be appreciated.

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import jobData from "./assets/data.json"
import JobBoardComponent from './components/JobBoardComponent';
import NavBar from './components/NavBar'
import EmailBar from './components/EmailBar'
import BannerPage from "./components/BannerPage"
import { filter } from 'domutils';
import FuncFilter from "./components/FuncFilter"
import LocFilter from "./components/LocFilter"
import ConFilter from './components/ConFilter';



function App() {
  const [jobs, setJobs] = useState([])
  const [filtered, setFiltered] = useState([])
  const [activeCategory, setActiveCategory] = useState(0)
  const [activeLocation, setActiveLocation] = useState(0)
  const [activeContract, setActiveContract] = useState(0)
  const [toggled, setToggled] = useState(true);
   
  useEffect(() => {
    setJobs(jobData)
  }, [])

  

  return (
    <div className="App w-auto">
      <NavBar />
      <BannerPage />
      <EmailBar />
      <FuncFilter 
      jobs={jobs} 
      setFiltered={setFiltered} 
      activeCategory={activeCategory} 
      setActiveCategory={setActiveCategory}
      activeLocation={activeLocation}
      setActiveLocation={setActiveLocation}
      setActiveContract={setActiveContract}
      activeContract={activeContract}
      />
      <LocFilter 
      jobs={jobs} 
      setFiltered={setFiltered} 
      activeLocation={activeLocation}
      setActiveLocation={setActiveLocation}
      setActiveCategory={setActiveCategory}
      activeCategory={activeCategory}
      setActiveContract={setActiveContract}
      activeContract={activeContract}
      />
      <ConFilter 
      jobs={jobs} 
      setFiltered={setFiltered} 
      activeLocation={activeLocation}
      setActiveLocation={setActiveLocation}
      setActiveCategory={setActiveCategory}
      activeCategory={activeCategory}
      setActiveContract={setActiveContract}
      activeContract={activeContract}
      />
      <div>
      { activeCategory == 0 ? jobs.map((job) => <JobBoardComponent toggled={toggled} setToggled={setToggled} job={job} key={job.id} />)
       : filtered.map((job) => <JobBoardComponent toggled={toggled} setToggled={setToggled}
      job={job} key={job.id} />)}  
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

JobBoard.js

````
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react"
function JobBoardComponent({ toggled, setToggled, job }) {

   const langAndTools = []
   const skill = job.skills
   const tools = job.tools
   if (skill && tools) {
      langAndTools.push(...skill)
      langAndTools.push(...tools)
   } 

   useEffect(() => {

      setToggled(toggled)
  
    }, [toggled])


    const handleClick = event => {
      setToggled(!toggled);
    };

return  ( 
   <div id="jobboard"  onClick={handleClick} className={`flex flex-col hover:bg-gray-100  bg-white shadow-md m-4 mb-20 px-6  -mt-10 rounded ${job.featured && 'border-l-4 border-black'}`}>
      <div>
         <img className="-mt-10 mb-4 w-20 h-20"src={job.logo} alt={job.company}></img>
      </div> 
      <div className="text-left  mt-1">
         <h3 className="font-mono font-bold text-blue-600">
         {job.company}
         {job.fresh && (<span className="text-blue-100 bg-blue-500 font-bold m-2 py-1 px-2 rounded-full">
         New</span>)}
         {job.featured && (<span className="text-white bg-gray-800 font-bold m-2 py-1 px-2 rounded-full">Featured</span>)}
         </h3>
         <h2 className="font-mono font-bold text-xl my-2">{job.position}</h2>
         <p className="font-mono text-gray-700">
            {job.postedAt} · {job.contract} · {job.location}
         </p>
      </div> 
      <div id="jobdesc" className={toggled ? "hidden font-mono my-10 " : "font-mono my-10"} >
         <h3>Who We Are:</h3>
         <p>{job.whoweare}</p>
         <br></br>
         <h3>Job Description:</h3>
         <p>{job.description}</p>
         <br></br>
         <br></br>
         <a  id="applybtn" target="_blank" href={job.joblink} className="font-mono text-white bg-gradient-to-r from-blue-500 via-blue-600 to-blue-700 hover:bg-gradient-to-br focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 dark:focus:ring-blue-800 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-32 py-2 text-center mr-2 content-center"> Apply </a>
         <br></br>
      </div>
      <div className="flex flex-wrap items-center mt-4 mr-4 pt-4 border-t-2 border-gray-300 border-solid">
      {langAndTools ? (
         langAndTools.map((langAndTool) => (
         <span className="text-blue-600 bg-blue-100 font-bold mr-4 mb-4 p-2 rounded">{langAndTool}</span>
         ))
      )
      : " "
      }   
      </div>
   </div> 
   )
}

 export default JobBoardComponent```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVlzt.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSoOC.png
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to only open a specific job post you need to check the id of the clicked job against the id of the job that you're mapping over.

In your handleClick callback you can pass in the selected job id:

```js
onClick={()=> handleClick(job.id)}
```

In App.js you can set a state to store this value:

```js
const [setSelectedId,setSelectedId] = useState("")
```

Then in your JobBoardComponent you can set the selected id:

```js
<JobBoardComponent handleClick={(id)=> setSelectedId(id)}
```

Now you have your selected id stored in state you can check this against the JobBoardComponent you're mapping over:

```js
<JobBoardComponent handleClick={(id)=> setSelectedId(id)} selected={selectedId === job.id}
```

This will pass a boolean into JobBoardComponent which you can use to then conditionally render whatever you want:

```js
...selected && // show info
```

This is known as lifting state up and is quite a common pattern in react worth learning. [Here are the React docs that explain it in more detail](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

Comment: i love stackoverflow. And all of you guys. Thanks for taking the time out of your day to answer!

Comment: @ShaunSmerling No problem. If you did find the solution posted helpful you can click the up arrow to show that it worked for you. You can do this for multiple answers

Comment: Okay i'll do that. Do you know how i'd be able to now close the job post? Right now, the only way to close an opened job post is to click another. Ideally, you'd just reclick the opened job post and it would close. I tried adding a close btn but just working through the logic.

Comment: You don't need to add a new closed button. If you think about the logic in my answer above we're setting the selected prop by checking selectedId against job.id. Since selected is selectedId === job.id then we simply need to check if that condition is already true; if so we can set selected to an empty string. Something like handleClick={(id)=> if (selectedId === job.id) { setSelectedId(id) } else { setSelectedId("") }}

Comment: Wouldn't the job post still stay open though? The logic makes sense if you are only closing a job posts when another is opened.Once u click on a post, the statement becomes true hence the reason it opens due to my className ternary operator e.g. className={selectedId ? "font-mono my-10" : "hidden font-mono my-10" }. Ive written the handleClick function as you've written. But the job post stays open unless another is clicked. Ideally the user could click a button to close said job post, or just click that opened job post to close it

Comment: Oops mistyped. If (selectedId !== id) { setSelectedId(id) } else { setSelectedId("")} should work. You're checking to see if the element you've clicked on (the id you pass up in your callback) is already selected (the selected id you store in state)

Comment: If that's solved your problem you can mark this answer as the 'accepted' answer so other's know this solution worked for you @ShaunSmerling

Answer (score 1):

@msmoorse solution is correct. To add on, the reason why you are facing this problem is because you only have one boolean `toggled` to control whether all the jobs are shown. Since all jobs share the same state, they are gonna either all show, or all hide.

If you want only one job to be shown at a time, follow @msmoorse's solution.
If you want to allow users to open multiple jobs at the same time, you will need an array or object to record which jobs are shown and which jobs are hidden.

```
const [jobStates, setJobStates] = useState(Array(numOfJobs).fill(false))
```

The handleClick function will look something like this

```
handleClick={(id)=> setJobStates(prevJobStates => {
  const newJobStates = prevJobStates
  newJobStates[id] = !prevJobStates[id]
  return newJobStates
})}
```